# Select Form for Embedded model with rails 4 mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid, simple-form

I have a embedded model, Document in the embedded model can only be created by the admin, but users can select in form the value that they want

```ruby
class User 
  include Mongoid::Document

  embeds_one :state_model, class_name: "state_model", cascade_callbacks: true

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :state_model

  attr_accessor :current_password, :job_title_str, :state_model_id

  convert_id_to_object :state_model_id, :state_model
end
```

```ruby
class UsersController << ApplicationController

  def update_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:state_model_id)
  end

end
```

```ruby
module ConvertIdToObject
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def convert_id_to_object(id, object)

      id, object = id, object

      if StateModel.by_id(id).present?

          object = StateModel.by_id(id)

        else

      end
    end
  end

end
```

```ruby
class StateModel
  include Mongoid::Document


  field :name, type: String, localize: true
  field :value, type: String

  scope :by_value, -> (value){ where({:value => value}) unless value == ''}
  scope :by_id, -> (id){ where({:id => id}) unless id == ''}


  embedded_in :user

  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates :value, presence: true, uniqueness: true

end
```

```ruby
= simple_form_for user  do |f|
  = f.input :state_model_id , collection: state_collection
  = f.button :submit
```

```ruby
Post:
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"patch",
 "authenticity_token"=>"3/pmSUHrKRx56ycbraKYL+mEuAiS9QlwWt/bTglgsio=",
 "user"=>{"state_model_id"=>"5612cb074d6f722582050000"},
 "commit"=>"Update User",
 "id"=>"bowtch"}
```

End I have a Notimplemented error raised by my usercontroller Like if don't accept state_model_id as a param ... I'm stuck here ...

Comment: What you're doing doesn't really make sense to me. `embeds_one :thing` is really just `field :thing, :type => Hash` with some Mongoid wrapping. There is no `state_models` collection inside MongoDB, just some `state_model` fields inside the `users` collection. `StateModel`s don't exist on their own, they only exist inside a `User`. Also, why `attr_accessor` instead of `field` to define the structure of your `User`s?

Comment: I have to add state_models dynamicaly, and other models will depend on this statemodel, if you think there's a better way to do this maybe I don't know it

Comment: I don't know the details of what you're trying to achieve so I can't say much. However, what do you expect `StateModel.by_id(id)` to do? There is no `state_models` collection (well, there is but it will always be empty), you can only query `StateModel` with respect to their `User`: `User.where('state_model._id' => some_id).state_model`. If you need to add them dynamically then you're really just populating Hash fields or perhaps moving Hash fields from one `User` to another.

Comment: In the ligt of what you say, It seems that I missuse embbeded model, maybe i will go back to a belongs_to relation. I juste want to create a collection of state (created on their own (I deleted the embbeded in line in my state_model)) that the users will pick from a select form but I don't want to put it as a field of the user

Comment: Maybe a Custom field will do the trick I'm reading about it, what do you Think

Comment: Depends. If `StateModel` needs to exist as an independent entity then embedding isn't the right place to start, if it doesn't have to exist as an independent entity then embedding might make sense. In any case, I don't think `attr_accessor` is what you want to use here, you want `field`.

Comment: Thx Mu, I keep digging ;)